# Codeigniter: "Table not found" error when data inserted after database creation

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm making an installer module for my Codeigniter application.

I'm creating the MySQL database and it's tables through code and want to insert user credentials into db during the installation process. Like this:

[image]

The problem I'm having is that after creation of database and it's tables, when I try to insert the user info into the database it gives error saying "The table 'user' doesn't exist" while the table actually exists.

Here is the code:

```
$this->load->dbforge();  //Create the database
$this->install_model->use_sql_string();   //Add the tables from a .sql file

$this->load->database($database_name);  //Load the created database

$this->install_model->add_the_user($username, $password));  //Insert user data
```

The database and tables are being created correctly. Only the last line of code gives the error.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Please help!

Comment: Where is `$database_name` and what it has in to it ?

Comment: `$database_name` comes from $_POST (the form) and it's got the name of database the user entered.

Comment: I don't know the syntax in CI but after the DB creation run a query `USE DBName`

Comment: @Mihai `$this->load->database($db_name)` does the same thing as `USE DBName`

Answer (score 1):

I think You should load the database first, than u should import .sql file.
so table will be created in loaded DB.

```
$this->load->dbforge();  //Create the database
$this->load->database($database_name);  //Load the created database
$this->install_model->use_sql_string();   //Add the tables from a .sql file
$this->install_model->add_the_user($username, $password));  //Insert user data
```